# I want to animate the appendChild() , so that it fades in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Hi I want to add fade in effect , to a chrome plugin which shows up using appendChild().

I want something like,

```
    document.body.appendChild(div).fadeIn(1000);
```

Is their a way to do so ?

Answer (score 4):

the `fadeIn()` method is provided by jQuery - Assuming `div` is a dom element reference, you need to get the jQuery wrapper for it and then call fadeIn

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
...
document.body.appendChild(div);
$(div).hide().fadeIn(1000);
```

it can even be written as

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
...
$(div).hide().appendTo(document.body).fadeIn(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`fadeIn()` is a jQuery method, not a DOM method so you need to call it on a jQuery object, not a DOM object.  In addition, you probably want to hide the element before appending it like this:

```
// assumes you already have an element to append in a variable named div
div.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(div);
$(div).fadeIn(1000);
```

Or, using more jQuery, it could be like this:

```
$(div).hide().appendTo(document.body).fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: it gives Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @CleanX - if you're going to use jQuery, then you have to include the jQuery script in your page.   `$` is a jQuery symbol in this context.  If it's not defined, then you probably haven't included jQuery in your page.

Comment: I have added the jquery script and it still say the samething.

Comment: @CleanX - The symbol `$` is defined by jQuery.  If that symbol is not defined, then jQuery is not being loaded correct OR something is undefining that symbol.  I can't really help much with why that is without seeing your actual page.

Answer (score 0):

Please try use this code

```
$('<div class="someelement"/>').appendTo('body');
$('.someelement').fadeIn();
```